# regex for email parsing in python

Tags: python, regex, email, expression

i'm asked to write regular expression which can catch multi-domain email addresses and implement it in python. so i came up with the following regular expression (and code;the emphasis is on the regex though), which i think is correct:

```
import re
regex = r'\b[\w|\.|-]+@([\w]+\.)+\w{2,4}\b'
input_string = "hey my mail is abc@def.ghi"
match=re.findall(regex,input_string)
print match
```

now when i run this (using a very simple mail) it doesn't catch it!! 
instead it shows an empty list as the output. can somebody tell me where did i go wrong in the regular expression literal?

Comment: Just google this! There's loads of content on it. Even on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: i know that there are tons of copy-and-paste email regular expressions out there, but this problem is hurting my brain; knowing that the regex is right, yet it's not working.

Comment: a) It doesn't output an empty string, it outputs `['def.']` (which is the only bit you're capturing with `()`). b) the regex is not right, you can't use `|` like that inside a character class - inside `[]` it matches the pipe character literally, it doesn't do either-or, and `\b` doesn't match at the end of a string, and the regex is broken for addresses like `example@example.google` which don't have a 2-4 digit TLD.

Comment: And on top of @TessellatingHeckler's notes, if you have capturing groups, `findall` returns the capture groups, not the full match. Change `([\w]+\.)` to `(?:\w+\.)` to change the parens to non-capturing (also removing the superfluous but harmless brackets; `\w` is a character class by itself).

Comment: you just need to make `([\w]+\.)+` to non-capturing group `(?:[\w]+\.)+`, because if you specify a capture, findall will extract that part only.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple one to start you off with

```
regex = r'\b[\w.-]+?@\w+?\.\w+?\b'
re.findall(regex,input_string)  # ['abc@def.ghi']
```

The problem with your original one is that you don't need the `|` operator inside a character class (`[..]`). Just write `[\w|\.|-]` as `[\w.-]` (If the `-` is at the end, you don't need to escape it).

Next there are way too many variations on legitimate domain names. Just look for at least one period surrounded by word characters after the `@` symbol:

```
@\w+?\.\w+?\b
```